# Ajuda com erro de ponteiro no Java

Tags: java, swing, estrutura-de-dados, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo um projeto de Fila de Banco com prioridade,

Eu fiz tudo da forma que eu aprendi, porém esta dando algum erro de ponteiro nulo que não estou conseguindo entender, alguém conseguiria por favor me ajudar a entender onde estou errando?

Link do projeto:
[Projeto Java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18HQ2WuWOJh40FO6Ko1GmSUVE1IsJVg9s/view?usp=sharing)

**classe controller:**

```
package bean;

import classes.Funcionario;
import classes.Fila;
import classes.Pessoa;


public class Bean {

 Fila filaNormal = new Fila();

 Fila filaPreferencial = new Fila();

 public boolean retirarSenha(Pessoa pessoa){

    boolean validaSenha = false;
    if(!pessoa.getNome().isEmpty() || !pessoa.getCpf().isEmpty()){
        if(pessoa.isTipoDeSenha()){
            filaPreferencial.enfileirar(pessoa);   
        }else{
            filaNormal.enfileirar(pessoa);
        }
        validaSenha = true;              
    }

    return validaSenha;
 }

 public Object retirarSenha(){
     if(filaPreferencial.temProximo()){
         return filaPreferencial.desenfileirar();
     }else{     
     return filaNormal.desenfileirar(); 
     }
 }
} // fim Bean
```

**classe que implementa a fila:**

```
package classes;


public class Fila {

    public Fila() {
    }

    public Fila(Pessoa[] fila, int ponteiroInicio, int ponteiroPercorrer, int     
ponteiroFim, int total) {
        this.fila = new Pessoa[10];
        this.ponteiroInicio = 0;
        this.ponteiroPercorrer = 0;
        this.ponteiroFim = 0;
        this.total = 0;
    }

    public Pessoa fila[];
    private int ponteiroInicio;
    private int ponteiroPercorrer;
    private int ponteiroFim;
    private int total;


    public int getPonteiroInicio() {
        return ponteiroInicio;
    }

    public void setPonteiroInicio(int ponteiroInicio) {
        this.ponteiroInicio = ponteiroInicio;
    }

    public int getPonteiroPercorrer() {
        return ponteiroPercorrer;
    }

    public void setPonteiroPercorrer(int ponteiroPercorrer) {
        this.ponteiroPercorrer = ponteiroPercorrer;
    }

    public int getPonteiroFim() {
        return ponteiroFim;
    }

    public void setPonteiroFim(int ponteiroFim) {
         this.ponteiroFim = ponteiroFim;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fila{" + "fila=" + fila + ", ponteiroInicio=" + 
ponteiroInicio + ", ponteiroPercorrer=" + ponteiroPercorrer + ",         
ponteiroFim=" + ponteiroFim + ", total=" + total + '}';
    }

    public void enfileirar(Pessoa cliente){
     if(cheia()){
         throw new RuntimeException("Fila cheia");
     }

    fila[getPonteiroFim()] = cliente;
        setTotal(total++);
    }

    public Pessoa desenfileirar(){
        if(vazia()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Fila vazia");
        }
        Pessoa cliente = fila[getPonteiroInicio()];
        setPonteiroInicio(ponteiroInicio++);
        setTotal(total--);
        return cliente;
    }

    public boolean cheia(){
    return this.total == this.fila.length;
    }

    public boolean vazia(){
    return this.total == 0;
    }

    public boolean temProximo(){
        return this.fila[getPonteiroInicio() + 1] != null;    
    }

}
```

**classe da pessoa:**

```
package classes;

public class Pessoa {

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    private String nome, cpf;
    private int senha;
    private boolean tipoDeSenha;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String cpf, int senha, boolean tipoDeSenha) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.tipoDeSenha = tipoDeSenha;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public int getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(int senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public boolean isTipoDeSenha() {
        return tipoDeSenha;
    }

    public void setTipoDeSenha(boolean tipoDeSenha) {
        this.tipoDeSenha = tipoDeSenha;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa{" + "nome=" + nome + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", senha=" +     
senha + ", tipoDeSenha=" + tipoDeSenha + '}';
    }
}
```

Action em um Jframe onde o cliente preenche os dados, é criado o objeto que será enfileirado:

```
private void btnRetirarSenhaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
    String nomeCliente = txtNome.getText();
    String cpf = txtCPF.getText();
    boolean preferencial = jCheckPreferencial.isSelected();
    int senha = 0; // substituit por método criador de senha; 
    pessoa.setNome(nomeCliente);
    pessoa.setCpf(cpf);
    pessoa.setTipoDeSenha(preferencial);
    pessoa.setSenha(senha);
    Bean b = new Bean();
    boolean validarSenha = b.retirarSenha(pessoa);

    if(validarSenha == false){
       lblErroSenha.setText("Necessário preencher todos os campos "
                                        + "indicados com o: *");
   }
}
```

Action em jFrame onde é desenfileirado um objeto e mostrado na tela:

```
private void btnChamarSenhaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    Bean b = new Bean();
    lblDados.setText(b.retirarSenha().toString());

}
```

**erro quando clicado botão de criar objeto:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at classes.Fila.cheia(Fila.java:89)
at classes.Fila.enfileirar(Fila.java:70)
at bean.Bean.retirarSenha(Bean.java:46)
at view.TelaCliente.btnRetirarSenhaActionPerformed(TelaCliente.java:119)
at view.TelaCliente.access$000(TelaCliente.java:15)
at view.TelaCliente$1.actionPerformed(TelaCliente.java:50)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**Erro quando clino no botão que deve desenfileirar e mostrar o objeto desenfileirado:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at classes.Fila.temProximo(Fila.java:97)
    at bean.Bean.retirarSenha(Bean.java:55)
    at     view.TelaFuncionario.btnChamarSenhaActionPerformed(TelaFuncionario.java:99)
    at view.TelaFuncionario.access$000(TelaFuncionario.java:13)
    at view.TelaFuncionario$1.actionPerformed(TelaFuncionario.java:43)
    at     javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at     javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:40    2)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.    java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege    (ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege    (ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege    (ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:    201)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116    )
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:    105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: e por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que possamos executar o codigo e ajuda-lo a resolver o problema.

Comment: Faltou fornecer um exemplo executável, senao fica complicado achar o problema.

Comment: Coloquei os erros, quanto ao tópico referenciado, acho que coloquei tudo o necessário para poder avaliar a aplicação e nada irrelevante, porém sou muito inciante então já peço desculpas desde já caso tenha código desnecessário.

Comment: nullpointer quase sempre precisa testar o fluxo do código. Como analisar fluxo de codigo sem executar? Ai complica ne. Voce precisa facilitar a vida de quem quer te ajudar tambem, ainda mais um codigo envolvendo 3 classes distintas.

Comment: Caso eu compartilhe o projeto no google drive é o suficiente para isso? Desculpa a quantidade de coisas não feitas.

Comment: Henrique, voce pode acessar o link que mencionei no primeiro comentário, nele tem orientaçoes de como criar um exemplo simples que pode ser testado.

Comment: Eu li ele, porém pra mim tudo que coloquei é necessário para verificar o erro.

Comment: Como verificar um erro de fluxo num codigo que nem é testavel? Estou tentando te orientar pois quero te ajudar, mas se vc nao quer se esforçar pra ser ajudado, fica dificil.

Comment: Eu estou me esforçando, eu só não estou realmente entendendo o que esta faltando. Eu li o tópico todo, mas eu não sei classificar o que é testável ou não, sei o básico de POO apenas por enquanto.

Comment: Coloquei o projeto no google drive e compartilhei o link, era isso que faltava @Articuno ?

Comment: Tente criar um projeto novo e colar todo esse codigo e veja se vai executar. Nao vai, isso que voce precisa fazer, remover dependencias e fornecer apenas o codigo relevante testavel, onde seja possivel executar e simular esse problema das filas.

Comment: @Articuno Sincera e honestamente não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer, poderia por favor me ajudar dando as direções?

Comment: Crie uma janela simples, com o basico para simular a fila, e depois adicione os botoes que possuem os listeners que causam o erro. Viu? Nao é tao complicado.

Comment: Boa tarde, fiz como sugeriu, recomecei do zero fazendo passo a passo e consegui, muito brigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O problema é que você tem dois construtores na classe Fila:

```
public Fila() {
}

public Fila(Pessoa[] fila, int ponteiroInicio, int ponteiroPercorrer, int ponteiroFim, int total) {
    this.fila = new Pessoa[10];
    this.ponteiroInicio = 0;
    this.ponteiroPercorrer = 0;
    this.ponteiroFim = 0;
    this.total = 0;
}
```

Repare que só o segundo construtor inicializa a variável `this.fila`.

Na classe `Bean`, você invoca somente o primeiro construtor - o que não inicializa a variável `this.fila`:

```
Fila filaNormal = new Fila();
Fila filaPreferencial = new Fila();
```

Acontece que quando você invoca os métodos `temProximo`, `cheia` ou `vazia`, você tenta acessar a variável `this.fila`. Acontece que ela ainda não foi inicializada (devido ao construtor utilizado). Isso acaba causando o `NullPointerException`:

```
public boolean temProximo(){
    return this.fila[getPonteiroInicio() + 1] != null;    
}
```

Uma solução para o seu problema é implementar corretamente os dois construtores:

```
public Fila() {
    this.fila = new Pessoa[10];
    this.ponteiroInicio = 0;
    this.ponteiroPercorrer = 0;
    this.ponteiroFim = 0;
    this.total = 0;
}

public Fila(Pessoa[] fila, int ponteiroInicio, int ponteiroPercorrer, int ponteiroFim, int total) {
    this.fila = fila;
    this.ponteiroInicio = ponteiroInicio;
    this.ponteiroPercorrer = ponteiroPercorrer;
    this.ponteiroFim = ponteiroFim;
    this.total = total;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui de outra forma mas usarei sua explicação para analisar o código no final de semana.